# In pairs for loop not looping inside of another in pairs loop

Tags: for-loop, lua, lua-table

I have an array inside of an object class that I'm attempting to loop though. Going though each object in the class is fine, but when it comes to the array in the specific object. I only goes though the first set and skips the rest.

I already set the index and value to a different name to not disturb the class loop, and that doesn't seem to be the problem.

[image: An image of the code in full]

I've also tested the loop without any of the code inside it (in case something in it was messing it up) it still wouldn't loop.
I attempted to use ipears, nothing changed
Tried using #char.noteGroup, noteType wouldn't compare properly and it also made the loop laggy
Switched e with j, no difference

Comment: It's likely that you have to replace `curNote[e]` with `curNote`.